# Dynamic html pages with Jade, NodeJS, Express

Tags: html, dynamic, node.js, pug, express

I have a big json object containing cell data from a sample spreadsheet that has been retrieved from redis keystore. I want to show it in a html table format in the jade template. But for now, all I can show it as is a json string.

I am also unclear about how to generate dynamic web pages using jade/express.

Sample JSON string am trying to pass:

```
{"1A":"Cell Data 1", "1B": "Cell Data 2",...}
```

It is data from an excel spreadsheet.

Please help me to clear this doubt.

Comment: or if there is any way to pass html to jade templates, that would help for now as well.

Comment: Could you post a row of the json?

Comment: the json generation is under my control. here is what i have:            {"1A":"Cell Data 1","1B":"Cell Data 2"} and so on. should i change the format? am pretty new to node and javascript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th Name
      th Food
  tbody
    - var items = [{name:'Dean',food:'Chicken'}, {name:'Paul',food:'steak'}]
    - each item in items
      tr
        td= item.name
        td= item.food
```

outputs

```
<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Food</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Dean</td><td>Chicken</td></tr><tr><td>Paul</td><td>steak</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

or more practically than defining the items array of objects in jade

```
var items = dynamicallyGenerateYourJson();
res.render('table', {
  items: items
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I should change the JSON format to [{cell:'1A',data:'Cell Data 1'},{cell:'1B',data:'Cell Data 2'}]

Comment: yes, an array of objects renders very cleanly to a table, one object per row, with the keys as columns

Comment: Well... I think you would change your JSON format to [{'A': 'A1 Data', 'B', 'B1 Data'}, {...row 2...}].